# Fix an image's colors

Tags: command-line, images

Let's say I have an image that is basically two colors, red and white. However there are also parts of the image that are a little bit off white. I want to change those parts to be white, so that the image only has two colors. What program can do that from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/convert.html) [-posterize](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#posterize) 2

hmm, that didn't work as expected

```
convert -colors 2 +dither gradient.png bicolor.png
```

**meh**, there is an intensity mapping that forces white into grey thus

```
# create a 2 color image from scratch to supply colors for mapping
$ convert -size 10x10 xc:white -fill red -draw 'rectangle 0 0 5 5' \
    -colors 2 +dither bicolor.gif
# map 'em, Danno!
$ convert -colors 2 -normalize +dither -remap bicolor.gif in.png out.png
```

worked. Note: a prior version of this answer used `mogrify` instead of `convert`, I changed it because mogrify overwrites the original in-place while convert doesn't but they use the same algorithms and arguments.

---

> [image: bicolor.gif] 
>   bicolor.gif
>   [image: in.png]  in.png
>   [image: out.png] 
>   out.png

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/ was far more helpful than the man pages